# JAX-WS Soap header and Body tag is different

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws

When I created soap request through JAX-WS, generated XML string was like below.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       Some header infos....
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        Nice body part.
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It seems weird beacause Header tag is different from others.
Is this correct with JAX-WS??

Comment: All the tags are in the same namespace; the structure is correct if slightly inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'd like to know how I can make the header tag like 'soap:Header'.